# Service not starting with Debugger.Break c# windows service

Tags: windows-services

With following code, by service does start but when I uncomment Debugger.Break() it doesn't. What's wrong.

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        #if DEBUG
             //Debugger.Break();
        #endif
    }
```

Further update, if I change the target framework to 3.5 it works but doesn't work in framework  4.0!!!